# How use jQuery plugin in Angular 7

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-plugins, angular7

I'm using a js plugin that extends jQuery to convert xml2json. ([plugin here](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/SjSrij))

I was using it within my legacy **AngularJs** application and it worked, but now that I have upgraded to **Angular7** I'm not sure how to set it up.

I have included both jQuery and the plugin in the `angular.json` file like this:

```
script: [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js", 
  "src/app/plugins/jquery.xml2json.js"  //Note: I've edited the position of the scripts
]
```

And then I use it like this:

```js
// app.component.ts
import * as $ from 'jquery'

export class AppComponent{
  myFunction() {
    let xmlDocument = "<tree>test</tree>";
    $.xml2json(xmlDocument);
  }
}
```

but I get this error

```
_plugins_jquery_xml2json_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.xml2json is not a function
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does `xml2json` require `jQuery`? You might need to load jQuery first.

Comment: @showdev Yes it does, but I have already tried loading jQuery first.

Comment: Maybe it requires the full version of jQuery, rather than the slim version?

Comment: @showdev I've tried that as well :)

Comment: Load jquery first and then replace your `import  * as $...` with `declare let $: any;`

Comment: @David that worked!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it when referencing JavaScript files in the angular.json file the angular compiler will insert them in one file organized by the order you put them in the Script array.
in your provided example it will write the `src/app/plugins/jquery.xml2json.js` content first then it will write the `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js` content after it.

please try to swap the positions of the items and let me know if this works.

Please Note that I have found this NPM package you can use to convert xml to json I think this is the same as the one you use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-xml2json

**UPDATE**
Sorry I didnt notice that you tried what @showdev said.

I have spend the time to find the issue but didnt reach to a solution but what I found is that the Angular is not loading the jquery the first place it always gave me `undefiend`.

If you can consider the NPM package that I mentioned it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@David's comment worked! I think I can't accept a comment as answer so I'll post it myself:

```js
// app.component.ts
//import * as $ from 'jquery' <-old

declare let $: any;          
export class AppComponent{
  myFunction() {
    let xmlDocument = "<tree>test</tree>";
    $.xml2json(xmlDocument);
  }
}
```

Also, the position of the script matters.